# Is there way to programmatically get the complete typeinfo of any type(class) in C++?

Tags: c++, types

While working in non IDE environment, we do not get support related to intellisense. Also sometime it good documentations of methods/API are also not readily available. Under these circumstances, it would be great if we can get the type information of underlying class which we are using. I think
there is similar functionality **help(type)** in **python** language. To explain it better, lets us see below sample program.

```
#include<iostream>

class Add {
private:
    int first;
    int second;
public:
    Add(int a, int b): first(a), second(b) {}
    ~Add() { }
    int PerformAdd(){
        int sum {0};
        sum = first + second;
        return sum;
    }
};


int main() {
    int m = 10;
    int n = 20;
    
    Add ad(m,n);
    std::cout << "Addition Of " << m << " and "<< n << " is: " << ad.PerformAdd()<<std::endl;

}
```

Now, when I **debug** it(for example gdb) and use below **ptype** commands, I get the complete type information of `class Add`.

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at Program.cpp:19
19          int m = 10;
(gdb) n
20          int n = 20;
(gdb)
22          Add ad(m,n);
(gdb)
23          std::cout << "Addition Of " << m << " and "<< n << " is: " << ad.PerformAdd()<<std::endl;
(gdb) whatis ad
type = Add
(gdb) ptype Add
type = class Add {
  private:
    int first;
    int second;

  public:
    Add(int, int);
    ~Add(int);
    int PerformAdd(void);
}
(gdb)
```

So I get the complete class interface(type) information when I have built code for debug mode. **I would like to know in case there is way to programmatically print a type of a class or any information closest to this when we have debug binary available?.**

This could be useful when we are working in non IDC with no internet access on the working terminal. I use help(type) functionality extensively in python environment when I encounter an error or looking what class/type offers for use.

Comment: Are you looking for `typeid` operator in C++ ? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typeid-operator-in-c-with-examples/

Comment: @Tushar No. Geeksforgeeks is also a terrible source for almost everything.

Comment: This is called reflection and C++ doesn't have it yet.

Comment: What keeps you from using a "lightweight" IDE? Like visual studio code? Because whatever you try to do will not be part of the core activity of developing functionality and the "problem" has already been solved for you

Comment: By `IDC` do you mean `IDE`?  gcc is written im C/C++, and it can print the class description, so clearly C/C++ can do it.  It does it by inderstanding the debug binary format and having access to the source code and maybe even some other intermediate files (not sure), but it is open source.  It won't be easy tobreplicate.  By far the easy solution will be to use gdb by 1000x or more.

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you dislike VS Code, you could still use the same language servers via the [Language Server Protocol](https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol), which is basically a dialect of JSON RPC. For example, you can use [LSP from VIM](https://www.vimfromscratch.com/articles/vim-and-language-server-protocol).

Comment: Thank you all for your input. My question is not because I dislike IDE/VS Code and all.. I wanted to know if it is possible as it would be helpful in certain situation. I understand that it should not be easy to achieve and thought to ask here after thinking lot about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a way to quickly print type info during development you could just invoke gdb programatically and call `ptype`.

i.e. a command line similar to: `gdb -ex 'ptype <TYPENAME>' -ex quit -q <EXE_NAME>`.

In C++ you could accomplish this with something like:

```cpp
#include<errno.h>

void help(const char* name) {
  std::string command = std::string("gdb -ex 'ptype ") + name + "' -ex quit -q ";
  command += program_invocation_name;
  system(command.c_str());
}
```

which could then be used like:

```cpp
int main() {
    help("Add"); // prints typeinfo synthesized from gdb

    Add ad(1, 2);
    std::cout << ad.PerformAdd() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Online example: [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/0ZsYNmQaM-)
(you unfortunately need to click on the cog in the top right corner -> Extra Compiler Flags and enter `-g` there; otherwise the example won't work because onlinegdb builds the elf file without debugging info by default)

**Disclaimers:**

- Your code needs to be compiled with `-g`, otherwise there won't be any debug info for gdb to print.
- `gdb` must be installed on the system, because we directly invoke it.
- This should obviously not be used in production code.

---

##### Manually reading the debug information

If you don't want to depend on gdb you can also parse the debugging info manually - be warned though that this is not as trivial as it might sound.

I'm going to assume that the executable is an [ELF-binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) with [DWARF debugging information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF).

An easy way to visualize the debugging information that is attached to an elf file is with the [`dwarfdump` program](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dwarfdump/dwarfdump.1.en.html)

For your executable it would for example produce the following debugging data:
`dwarfdump foo.o`

```
< 1><0x0000520b>    DW_TAG_class_type
                      DW_AT_name                  Add
                      DW_AT_byte_size             0x00000008
                      DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf_test/foo.cpp
                      DW_AT_decl_line             0x0000000d
                      DW_AT_decl_column           0x00000007
                      DW_AT_sibling               <0x00005295>
< 2><0x00005219>      DW_TAG_member
                        DW_AT_name                  first
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf_test/foo.cpp
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000010
                        DW_AT_decl_column           0x00000009
                        DW_AT_type                  <0x000039d8>
                        DW_AT_data_member_location  0
< 2><0x00005226>      DW_TAG_member
                        DW_AT_name                  second
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf_test/foo.cpp
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000011
                        DW_AT_decl_column           0x00000009
                        DW_AT_type                  <0x000039d8>
                        DW_AT_data_member_location  4
< 2><0x00005233>      DW_TAG_subprogram
                        DW_AT_external              yes(1)
                        DW_AT_name                  Add
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf_test/foo.cpp
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000013
                        DW_AT_decl_column           0x00000005
                        DW_AT_linkage_name          _ZN3AddC4Eii
                        DW_AT_accessibility         DW_ACCESS_public
                        DW_AT_declaration           yes(1)
                        DW_AT_object_pointer        <0x00005249>
                        DW_AT_sibling               <0x00005259>
< 3><0x00005249>        DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                          DW_AT_type                  <0x00005295>
                          DW_AT_artificial            yes(1)
< 3><0x0000524e>        DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                          DW_AT_type                  <0x000039d8>
< 3><0x00005253>        DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                          DW_AT_type                  <0x000039d8>
< 2><0x00005259>      DW_TAG_subprogram
                        DW_AT_external              yes(1)
                        DW_AT_name                  ~Add
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf_test/foo.cpp
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000014
                        DW_AT_decl_column           0x00000005
                        DW_AT_linkage_name          _ZN3AddD4Ev
                        DW_AT_accessibility         DW_ACCESS_public
                        DW_AT_declaration           yes(1)
                        DW_AT_object_pointer        <0x0000526e>
                        DW_AT_sibling               <0x00005279>
< 3><0x0000526e>        DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                          DW_AT_type                  <0x00005295>
                          DW_AT_artificial            yes(1)
< 3><0x00005273>        DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                          DW_AT_type                  <0x000039d8>
                          DW_AT_artificial            yes(1)
< 2><0x00005279>      DW_TAG_subprogram
                        DW_AT_external              yes(1)
                        DW_AT_name                  PerformAdd
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf_test/foo.cpp
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000015
                        DW_AT_decl_column           0x00000009
                        DW_AT_linkage_name          _ZN3Add10PerformAddEv
                        DW_AT_type                  <0x000039d8>
                        DW_AT_accessibility         DW_ACCESS_public
                        DW_AT_declaration           yes(1)
                        DW_AT_object_pointer        <0x0000528e>
< 3><0x0000528e>        DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                          DW_AT_type                  <0x00005295>
                          DW_AT_artificial            yes(1)
```

This is the raw debug data that gdb uses to synthesize the C++ class definition that is printed by `ptype`.
(in case you're interested: most of the `ptype` implementation can be found in [`c-typeprint.c` in the gdb sources](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/c-typeprint.c;hb=HEAD) - dwarf parsing is in the [`dwarf2` subdirectory](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=tree;f=gdb/dwarf2;h=9e8a33b1d79e8e2a2b4b2538e31a8632ba219d1e;hb=HEAD))

To parse this data from C++ you need to link against [`libdwarf`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libdwarf-dev).

Here's a small sample program that lists all known classes and their data members in a given binary `foo.o` using `libdwarf`:

compile with `g++ sample.cpp -ldwarf -o sample.o` or similar:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libdwarf/dwarf.h>
#include <libdwarf/libdwarf.h>

void iterate_dies_recursively(
  Dwarf_Debug dbg, Dwarf_Die die,
  std::string indent = ""
) {

    Dwarf_Error error;

    // get die tag (namespace, class, member, etc...)
    Dwarf_Half tag = 0;
    dwarf_tag(die, &tag, &error);

    // get die name
    char* name = nullptr;
    dwarf_die_text(die, DW_AT_name, &name, &error);
    if(!name) name = const_cast<char*>("");


    std::string childIndent = indent;
    switch(tag) {
    case DW_TAG_namespace:
        std::cout << indent << "namespace " << name << " {" << std::endl;
        childIndent += "\t";
        break;
    case DW_TAG_class_type:
        std::cout << indent << "class " << name << " {" << std::endl;
        childIndent += "\t";
        break;
    case DW_TAG_member: {
        // get name of type
        // this will only work for basic types
        char* type_name = const_cast<char*>("/* unknown */");
        Dwarf_Attribute type_attr = nullptr;
        Dwarf_Off type_offset = 0;
        Dwarf_Die type_die = nullptr;
        if(
            dwarf_attr(die, DW_AT_type, &type_attr, &error) == DW_DLV_OK &&
            dwarf_global_formref(type_attr, &type_offset, &error) == DW_DLV_OK &&
            dwarf_offdie_b(dbg, type_offset, true, &type_die, &error) == DW_DLV_OK &&
            type_die
        ) {
            dwarf_die_text(type_die, DW_AT_name, &type_name, &error);
            dwarf_dealloc(dbg, type_die, DW_DLA_DIE);
        }

        std::cout << indent << type_name << " " << name << ";" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    }

    // process children
    Dwarf_Die child = nullptr;
    if(dwarf_child(die, &child, &error) == DW_DLV_OK && child) {
        iterate_dies_recursively(
            dbg, child,
            childIndent
        );
        dwarf_dealloc(dbg, child, DW_DLA_DIE);
    }

    switch(tag) {
    case DW_TAG_namespace:
        std::cout << indent << "}" << std::endl;
        break;
    case DW_TAG_class_type:
        std::cout << indent << "};" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    // process siblings
    Dwarf_Die sibling = nullptr;
    if(dwarf_siblingof_b(dbg, die, true, &sibling, &error) == DW_DLV_OK && sibling) {
        iterate_dies_recursively(
            dbg, sibling,
            indent
        );
        dwarf_dealloc(dbg, sibling, DW_DLA_DIE);
    }
}


void iterate_all_compilation_units(Dwarf_Debug dbg) {
    for (;;) {
        Dwarf_Unsigned cu_header_length = 0;
        Dwarf_Half version_stamp = 0;
        Dwarf_Unsigned abbrev_offset = 0;
        Dwarf_Half address_size = 0;
        Dwarf_Half length_size = 0;
        Dwarf_Half extension_size = 0;
        Dwarf_Sig8 type_signature;
        Dwarf_Unsigned typeoffset = 0;
        Dwarf_Unsigned next_cu_header_offset = 0;
        Dwarf_Half header_cu_type = 0;
        Dwarf_Error error;

        int res = dwarf_next_cu_header_d(
            dbg,
            true, // is_info
            &cu_header_length,
            &version_stamp,
            &abbrev_offset,
            &address_size,
            &length_size,
            &extension_size,
            &type_signature,
            &typeoffset,
            &next_cu_header_offset,
            &header_cu_type,
            &error
        );

        // done
        if(res == DW_DLV_NO_ENTRY) {
            break;
        }

        Dwarf_Die sibling_die = nullptr;
        res = dwarf_siblingof_b(
            dbg,
            nullptr, // dw_die
            true,    // dw_is_info
            &sibling_die, // dw_return_siblingdie
            &error
        );

        if(res == DW_DLV_OK && sibling_die) {
            iterate_dies_recursively(dbg, sibling_die);
            dwarf_dealloc(dbg, sibling_die, DW_DLA_DIE);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
  Dwarf_Debug dbg = nullptr;
  Dwarf_Error error;

  // init dwarf
  dwarf_init_path(
      "./foo.o",          // path
      nullptr,            // true_path_out_buffer
      0,                  // true_path_bufferlen
      O_RDONLY,           // access
      DW_GROUPNUMBER_ANY, // groupnumber
      0,                  // errhand
      nullptr,            // errarg
      &dbg,               // dbg
      nullptr,            // reserved1
      0,                  // reserved2
      nullptr,            // reserved3
      &error              // error
  );

  // iterate over all compilation units
  iterate_all_compilation_units(dbg);

  // cleanup dwarf
  dwarf_finish(dbg, &error);
  return 0;
}
```

**Disclaimer:**

- This is just a small example, so most error checking has been elided.
- The type for members will only work in simple cases - for it to always work you need to follow the die chain ([see here for an example](https://github.com/avast/libdwarf/blob/7d4f63f44d44386744628ee1bca84afc43a56583/libdwarf/dwarfdump/print_die.c#L1578-L1639))
- You probably will have to handle a lot more tags & attributes (like `DW_TAG_subprogram` for member functions, `DW_TAG_structure_type` for structs, etc... - `DW_AT_accessibility` for private / protected / public, etc...)

For your example binary this would print the following output:

```
namespace std {
    namespace __cxx11 {
        class basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > {
            pointer _M_p;
            /* unknown */ _M_local_buf;
            size_type _M_allocated_capacity;
            /* unknown */ npos;
            _Alloc_hider _M_dataplus;
            size_type _M_string_length;
            /* unknown */ ;
        };
    }
    namespace __exception_ptr {
        class exception_ptr {
            /* unknown */ _M_exception_object;
        };
    }
    class type_info {
    };
    /* unknown */ value;
    /* unknown */ value;
    namespace __swappable_details {
    }
    namespace __swappable_with_details {
    }
    namespace __debug {
    }
    class allocator<char> {
    };
    class initializer_list<char> {
        iterator _M_array;
        size_type _M_len;
    };
    // [...]
}
// [...]
class Add {
    int first;
    int second;
};
```